# How to overload dereference operator of std::list for range-based for?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I am trying to handle `std::list` of pointer type, like this:

```
std::list<int*> pNums;
```

Originally, iterating this container with **range-based for loop** will look like this :

```
for(int* pNum : pNums)
{
    std::cout << (*pNum) << std::endl;
}
```

However, I want to iterate this container with a **value**, not a **pointer**, like below:

```
for(int num : Range(pNums))
{
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

|
Here, `Range` is a custom wrapping-class of `std::list<int*>`, something should be defined in this manner, I guess:

```
class Range
{
    Range(std::list<int*>& _list) : list(_list) {}
    std::list<int*>& list;

    // Basically inherit the original iterator
    class custom_const_iterator : std::list<int*>::const_iterator
    {
        // Define an overloaded dereference operator
        const int& operator*() const
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    };

public:
    custom_const_iterator begin() { return ...; }
    custom_const_iterator end()   { return ...; }
};
```

So, my question is, what should I write down for class `Range`?

Comment: what's wrong with `for(auto pNum: pNums) { auto& num = *pNum; ... }` ?

Comment: @Jeffrey - Yes it does work, but it JUST works! I am curious about a neater way to write down codes :D

Comment: Check the KISS principle. Smart-alec code is hard to maintain. But hey, that's subjective. :-)

Comment: see also [`boost::adaptors::indirect`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the following approach (explanation in the comments):

```
class Range
{
private:
    // Store iterators to the begin and the end of the range, 
    // rather than a reference to the whole list
    std::list<int*>::const_iterator first;
    std::list<int*>::const_iterator last;

    class iterator
    {
    private:
        std::list<int*>::const_iterator it;

    public:
        explicit iterator(std::list<int*>::const_iterator i) : it(i) {}

        // you should define all the other operators
        // that a std::list iterator has!
        iterator& operator++()
        { 
            ++it;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            it++; 
            return *this;
        }

        // just dereference to get the value
        const int& operator*() const { return **it; }

        // these two are quite important for basic functionality
        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const { return it == rhs.it; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const { return it != rhs.it; }
    };

public:
    Range(std::list<int*>& _list) 
        : first(_list.begin()), last(_list.end()) 
    {}

public:
    iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
    iterator end()   { return iterator(last); }
};
```

Comment: My intention was to minimize code to be written by overloading only dereference operator, but this is acceptable! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, why do you prefer store 2 iterators inside the class rather than a reference to the whole list?

Comment: @Moon `by overloading only dereference operator` I understand, but that's really not common. I don't recomment to have an `std` class as a base such as `std::list<>::iterator`... `why do you prefer store 2 iterators` Because that is the way the Standard Library usually defines functions/classes. If you take a look at `<algorithm>` for example, you will see all algorithms take a pair of iterators rather than entire containers. In a perfect world you would define `Range` as a template and `first` and `last` will be generic rather than hard-coded as `std::list<>::iterator`.

Comment: @Moon "*My intention was to minimize code to be written by overloading only dereference operator*" - in order for a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to operate correctly, your `Range` class MUST expose `begin()` and `end()` methods that return an iterator type that implements the `!=`, `++`, and `*` operators **at a minimum**. Implementing only the `*` operator is not enough.